# How two concatenate two dataframes has only one identical column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to concatenate these two dataframes in pandas.

df1:

```
Month Date ID
12    01   01
12    01   02
12    02   03 
12    02   01
```

df2:

```
ID Name
01 Jack
02 Lu
03 James
```

new df:

```
Month Date ID Name
12    01   01 Jack
12    01   02 Lu
12    02   03 James
12    02   01 Jack
```

Can anyone help me with this?
See clear form here:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr8k8.png)

Comment: You are looking for merge, df1.merge(df2). Its a duplicate

Comment: `pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left', on=['ID'])`

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='ID')
```